# Slurm does not allocate the resources and keeps waiting

Tags: slurm

I'm trying to use our cluster but I have issues. I tried allocating some resources with:

```
salloc -N 1 --ntasks-per-node=5 bash
```

but It keeps wainting on:

> salloc: Pending job allocation ...
>
> salloc: job ... queued and waiting for resources

or when I try:

```
srun -N1 -l echo test
```

it lingers at waiting queue!

Am I making a mistake or there is something wrong with our cluster?

Comment: Not enough info to answer. Is the cluster empty? Or there are other jobs using it? There are free resources for you? There are higher priority jobs than your waiting in the queue? Is backfilling enabled, or it works as a FIFO?

Comment: @Poshi these are actually the kind of information I was looking for. how can I check if the cluster is empty or how much/many of the resources alr allocatable? how can i find the priority of the jobs? what is backfilling and FIFO?

Comment: Check the [SLURM documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart.html). In general. All this information is spread in the different commands offered by SLURM. Anyways, in general, if SLURM makes you wait... it is not a system error (maybe a user error, if you are asking for something that does not exist, but in that case, the state of the job is not Priority or Resources).

Comment: @Poshi any ways to list the number of free cores available/free at the moment? are there any options for `sinfo` showing this information?

Comment: A quick way to run `sinfo -o%C` ; it shows Allocated/Idle/Other(down)/Total number of CPUs

Comment: @Poshi strange. There are over 500 CPUs available but I have been waiting for one hour now! this is what I get from above command: `201/559/0/760`

Comment: Maybe you are asking for all cores of a node and all nodes are running 1 core jobs. Or maybe you are asking for more memory per core than memory available in the machine. Or maybe there is a higher priority job in front of you asking for 700 cores and you won't start until this job get its share... There can be many reasons to have your job waiting. Before complaining, you should check that all requirements are met and the job does not start. I bet there's some resource that you need that is not available.

Comment: the resources I'm asking for is basically `salloc -N 1 --ntasks-per-node=50 bash` I do not specify the node, hoping slurm will give me one of the free ones. I also do not specify memory. Should I? the squeue command show me a list of running and waiting people. In that list I have a priority tag under `NODELIST(REASON)`. Is there any way to see how much/many resources there are using or asking for?

Comment: I tried the `sinfo -N -l` command and it also shows there a lot of nodes idle. I tried a very simple sbatch from [this tutorial](https://support.ceci-hpc.be/doc/_contents/QuickStart/SubmittingJobs/SlurmTutorial.html), allocating one CPU with 100mb memory. I have been waiting for hours. there is something wrong with the system.

Comment: Also possibly worth restarting the slurm daemons ```sudo slurmctld restart; sudo slurmd restart```

Comment: @Foad did you ever solve this?

Comment: @ElementalStorm Gee! this was already a long time ago. have you tried asking the question on [r/SLURM](https://www.reddit.com/r/SLURM/) and [r/HPC](https://www.reddit.com/r/HPC/) subreddits? I honestly do not remember if I ever solved this spcefic issue but I did get to run the simulations successfully eventually.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to set a time limit for the Slurm job using the option `--time`, for instance set a limit of 10 minutes like this:

```
srun --job-name="myJob" --ntasks=4 --nodes=2 --time=00:10:00 --label echo test
```

Without time limit, Slurm will use the partition's default time limit. The issue is that sometimes this might be set to infinity or to several days, so this might cause a delay in the start of the job. To check the partition's default time limit use:

```
$ sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST 
prod*        up   infinite    198  ....
gpu*         up 4-00:00:00     70  ....
```

From the [Slurm docs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html):

> `-t, --time=<time>`
> *Set a limit on the total run time of the job allocation. If the requested time limit exceeds the partition's time limit, the job will be left in a PENDING state (possibly indefinitely). The default time limit is the partition's default time limit. When the time limit is reached, each task in each job step is sent SIGTERM followed by SIGKILL.*